# Reciveing an error while downloading a package gunicorn

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pip, web-hosting

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\Python310\Scripts\gunicorn.exe' -> 'C:\Python310\Scripts\gunicorn.exe.deletem

Answer (score 0):

Try installing your package like this:

```
pip install 'package name' --user
```